# SSD with Phison PS3111 controller repairing

Tags: identification, components, component-selection, ssd

I broke my SSD after applying 28 V and I am trying to repair it. But need a description of a component that is marked red in the image. I guess it is a fuse or something like that.

Could anybody please help?
[image]

Comment: The voltage regulator on it is toast. Best case scenario you can leave it to a specialist to extract the data for you.

Comment: Are there any markings/designators close to the part, that your red highlighting might have covered? Judging by the components's size and pin count I'd guess it is an optocoupler, havent had any luck finding one though.

Comment: @PatrickFiedler An optocoupler is super unlikely on an SSD. What would need isolation?

Comment: Hi @PatrickFiedler. There is QFN-10 package component above red square marked as "FNC1B". I thing it is a power controller. The component in red square and "FNC1B" are driving same line.  Real broken component is "FNC1B" according to my opinion. I detached "FNC1B" and I will mount a component that is in red square.  This picture has same configuration with my SSD , only difference, my pcb contain FNC1B , this PCB contain a component in red square. If you tell me what  "FNC1B" marking component is, I am okey with that.

Comment: @winny very fair point, none that I can think of. Bad case of tunnel vision, I've been dealing a lot with optocouplers lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [Polytronics SMD1210P700SLR](https://www.pttc.com.tw/DataSheets/Data%20Sheet%20for%20SMD%20SLR%20Series.pdf) PTC.

Comment: Thank you so much.